# JQuery and radio buttons

Tags: jquery

```
<form id="Numbers1"
<table id="numbers">
    <tr>
        <th>
            prvi_br
        </th>
        <th>
            drugi_br
        </th>
        <th>
            treci_br
        </th>
    </tr>
<% int rb = 1; %>
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>

        <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.prvi_br) %>
        <input type="radio" name="<%= Html.Encode(rb) %>"  value="<%= Html.Encode(rb) %>" id='<%= Html.Encode(item.prvi_br) %>'/>

        </td>
        <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.drugi_br) %>
        <input type="radio" name="<%= Html.Encode(rb) %>" value="<%= Html.Encode(rb) %>" id='<%= Html.Encode(item.drugi_br) %>'/>

        </td>
        <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.treci_br) %>
        <input type="radio" name="<%= Html.Encode(rb) %>" value="<%= Html.Encode(rb) %>" id='<%= Html.Encode(item.treci_br) %>'/>

        </td>
        <% rb=rb+1; %>
    </tr>  
<% } %>

</table>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
</form>
```

With this script I get some info of selected radio:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var thevalue1;
    var thevalue2;

    $("#Numbers1").submit(function() {
    $("input:radio:checked").each(function() {
            thevalue1 = $("input:radio:checked").attr('id');
            thevalue2 = $("input:radio:checked").val();
            alert(thevalue1 + thevalue2); 
        });          
    });
});
</script>
```

If I have more rows this alert every time prints the information of first selected radio, why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for every checked radio button, you call `$("input:radio:checked").attr('id')` which returns the id attribute of the first thing that matches `"input:radio:checked"`.

```
$("input:radio:checked").each(function() {
        Element = $(this);
        var thevalue1 = Element.attr('id');
        var thevalue2 = Element.val();
        alert(thevalue1 + thevalue2); 
    });
```

Comment: Tnx, you solved my problem.Can you help me with posting this info to controller action. I need something like this $.post("/Controller/Action", { thevalue1: thevalue1, thevalue2: thevalue2 }, function(data) {
                alert("form posted");
            });

Comment: this way of posting data is good but again only for one radio, how to solve this